# Removing PATH from the Windows DLL Search Order

Tags: windows

There exists a class of bugs on Windows where an unprivileged attacker can write a DLL to a location on disk, then add that location to the PATH variable. Then, when an elevated user process is trying to load a DLL with the same name, it will eventually search the locations in the PATH variable to try to find it, giving a clear path to privilege escalation.

The desktop application search order is listed here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-for-desktop-applications

What I'd like to do is remove the PATH variable from that search order.

There is this function in the Win32 API:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-setdefaultdlldirectories

But it is as yet unclear to me if this will work when you're running a .Net Core application that could conceivably load different DLLs depending on your hardware (display drivers for example).

Does anyone have experience removing PATH from the search order?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't PATH user specific?  This would mean that an unprivileged user would not be able to set the PATH for another user.